# Multiple progress in same Progress Indicator

Tags: flutter

How do I go about having multiple progresses in the same progress indicator?

Do I have to create a custom widget or is there a easier way to accomplish this?

Reference Image:
[image: Progress Slider Reference]

Comment: `child: Stack(
children: [
LinearProgressIndicator(value: 0.6),
LinearProgressIndicator(value: 0.35, backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, color: Colors.orange),
LinearProgressIndicator(value: 0.25, backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, color: Colors.red),
],
),`

Comment: @pskink Thank you! This gets the job done. Please post this as the answer.

Comment: your welcome, post a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reference to [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)'s comment, the following works.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    LinearProgressIndicator(
      value: 0,
    ),
    LinearProgressIndicator(
      value: 0.75,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
    ),
    LinearProgressIndicator(
      value: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ],
);
```